# IntersectionObserver rootMargin's positive and negative values are not working

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

The code for setting the `rootMargin` is shown below.

```
let observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "100px",
    threshold: []
};
```

When I set it to `100px`, the root element's bounding box isn't growing 100px; when I set it to `-100px`, the root element's bounding box isn't shrinking 100px.

Here is an [example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6a32tb9/2/). The example is taken directly from [MDN's documentation of IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), and I only changed the value of `rootMargin`.

Comment: I'm having a same issue here. Will post if I find update.

Comment: i didn't realise rootMargin was for the margin for the root, not for the element being observed. It makes sense, since the viewport is a scrollable area in the screen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your example on jsFiddle, your `IntersectionObserver` is in a `iframe` (jsFiddle wrap all the code in a iframe). For works in a `iframe` you must set the root with the iframe element.

In general, `rootMargin` works well if you set the `root` element with the correct element (the element with the scrollbar). Eg.:

```
let observerOptions = {
    root: document.getElementById("parentScroll"),
    rootMargin: "100px",
    threshold: []
};
```

Try your code in a classic html file and probably it works with `root: null`, but it will never works on jsFiddle.